# NSLayoutConstraints not being activated when rotating

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am making a custom layout which basically requires me to change the position and size of the subviews for events such as device rotation, class size change, user events (button tap), etc. Furthermore, depending on the state of my view, a layout can be repeated. For example, when button A is tapped and the device is in landscape, the layout is the same as the default portrait layout.

Due to this, instead of just using something like Vary for Traits, I decided to link my constraints as IBOutlets and activate/deactivate them depending on the state I desire.

However, only when rotating, there are some specific constraints that are not activated/deactivated immediately, which ends up creating a not-desired layout.

Here is some detail on what I am doing:

- All constraints that I need to change are connected as IBOutlets.
- The update of the constraints is being done using `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` to trigger the update and doing the ACTUAL activation/deactivation of the constraints inside `updateViewConstraints`
- Yes, I have called `super.updateViewConstraints`
- No, there are no console logs telling me that XCode has autorecovered from some constraint incoherence (**this bugs me the most**)
- I am deactivating first, then activating the desired constraints using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()/deactivate()`
- For rotation, I have tried calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` both inside `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` as well as by registering to `deviceOrientationDidChange` notification. Both with the same results.
- `view.layoutIfNeeded()` is being called after updating the constraints also.

I will try to paste screenshots, but basically the flow is as follows:

Expected Result:

```
1. Open app -> View shows Layout A
2. Rotate to landscape -> View changes to Layout B
3. Press button 1 -> View changes to Layout C
4. Press same button 1 again -> View changes back to Layout B
5. Keep pressing button -> View keeps toggling between layout C and B
```

Actual result:

```
1. Open app -> View shows Layout A
2. Rotate to landscape -> View changes to broken version of Layout B
3. Press button -> View changes to Layout C
4. Press same button again -> View changes back to Layout B
5. Keep pressing button -> View keeps toggling between layout C and B
```

As you can see, almost everything looks fine except that step 2, where the layout is broken.

I have also tried using the visual debugger (as there are no error logs in the console) and after checking my views constraints, I have realized that in step 2 some constraints are not being activated/deactivated, although I am manually doing so in code and I have verified that this is being executed in `updateViewConstraints`.

Thank you for your reading this and hope you might be able to help me.

Comment: Try calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` for `deviceOrientationDidChange`.

Comment: Hi @vacawama, `layoutIfNeeded` is being called after updating the constraints also.